# OneDrive for Busniess login Issue from Tablet

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business

One of my user is unable to login to OneDrive for Business from App on Tablet. But he is able to login through web.

He has "Enterprise Mobility + Security E3
SharePoint Online (Plan 1)"   licenses.   I hope there are enough to login to ODFB.

Does anyone know why he is able to login to ODFB through web but not through the APP?